# Display blank lines at half-height in fancyvrb Verbatim environment

Tags: line-spacing, verbatim, catcodes

I'm typesetting code that includes lots of blank lines, like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
def xyz():
    """Some documentation.

    More docs.

    More docs."""

    some code

    more code
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

For compactness, I'd like to shrink the blank lines (left is before, right is after, red indicates blank lines):

[image: before/after showing shrunk blank lines]

Note that I don't want to change the normal line spacing (the `def` in the example above doesn't get closer to the `"""` right below it).

I need `fancyvrb` as the contents are actually generated using pygments.  I tried reading through the definition of `Verbatim` using `latexdef`.  It seems that it makes `^^M` active and that's how it preserves newlines.  I imagine I could redefine that to count how many newlines we've seen in a row, but I'm not sure how to check whether they were immediately consecutive — maybe an `if@nextchar`?

As a first step, I tried adding markers manually to shrink the lines:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
def xyz():
    """Some documentation.
\unskip\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    More docs.
\unskip\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    More docs.
    """
\unskip\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    some code
\unskip\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    more code
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

But I got an error, and I can't tell where it comes from:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.8 \unskip\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
```

**How can I reduce the height of blank lines in Verbatim environments?**

Comment: As always: never use the `minimal` class for MWEs. That is not what it is for. It is missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I didn't realize.

Comment: @Bernard Ouch, thanks so much for fixing that typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@FV@emptyline

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active%
\gdef\FancyVerbGetLine#1^^M{%
  \@nil%
  \FV@CheckEnd{#1}%
  %% modification begin
  \if@FV@emptyline
    \vskip-.5\baselineskip
  \fi
  %% modification end
  \ifx\@tempa\FV@EnvironName%            % True if end is found
    \ifx\@tempb\FV@@@CheckEnd\else\FV@BadEndError\fi%
    \let\next\FV@EndScanning%
  \else%
    \def\FV@Line{#1}%
    %% modification begin
    \ifx\FV@Line\@empty
      \global\@FV@emptylinetrue
    \else
      \global\@FV@emptylinefalse
    \fi
    %% modification end
    \def\next{\FV@PreProcessLine\FV@GetLine}%
  \fi%
  \next}%
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[numberblanklines=false,numbers=left]
def xyz():
    """Some documentation.

    More docs.

    More docs.
    """

    some code

    more code
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, thanks a lot.